# Is :last-child:before pseudo selector correct?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is the below CSS selector correct ?

```
:last-child:before
```

I've never seen way like this, but it works very well.

I wonder this way is correct or not.

Comment: Horrible question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: When it `works very well`, then what's the point in getting someone else's opinion whether it is correct or no. If it works, it probably is correct

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ not necessary, deprecated tags still works, nesting block elements inside `p` still works doesn't mean they are correct

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is absolutely correct. It simply selects `last-child` of a given parent and embeds content `before` that element.

For example, we want to target `last-child` of `ul` element and we want to add an arrow before the last element.

```
ul li:last-child:before {
    content: "> ";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BX9gn/)

---

Also, would like to inform you that `last-child` won't respect the type of the element, it will simply select `last-child` of a parent, regardless of any element, if you want to target SPECIFIC element which is `last-child` to it's parent, use `last-of-type` instead of `last-child`